# 18.04 LTS Nautilus jpeg thumbnails not displaying

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, thumbnails, jpeg

I recently did a clean install of 18.04 LTS on a Lenovo Laptop. 
The thumbnail previews do not display for common files like JPEGs and mp4 files.

I have tried changing the settings in Preferences to thumbnail the largest possible jpeg and to display thumbnails for all connected drives or only local drives. None of these had any effect.

I have looked for others with this problem and have not found anything helpful.